# How to use Reactor (Spring WebClient) to do analogue of for loop

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

I'm quite new to Reactor (Spring5 WebClient) and though I have figured how to do simple request and process it's output with map or flatmap I need to do a bit harder task now:

I have an endpoint which I can not change.

basic signature of this endpoint call is Get
`{host}/{endpointName}?System={integer from 1 to 3}&Form={integer from 1 to 5}`

I need to call it repeatedly and to process output for this pairs:

```
{1, 1},
{1, 2},
{1, 3},
{1, 4},
...
{3, 2},
{3, 4},
{3, 5}
```

For one request it would be for example:

```
WebClient.create().get()
  .uri(uri -> uri.scheme("http")
    .host(myHost)
    .path(myPath)
    .queryParam("System", 1)
    .queryParam("Form", 1)
    .build())
  .exchange()
  .flatMap(response -> {
   //process response and produce desired output
   });
```

What I try to do is to:
1. Make multiple requests (basically iterating over map tha contains all pairs mentioned above)
2. Process each request result (processed result is added to json array that was created before WebClient)
3. When all requests are made - give "combined output".

Example: if request with combination 1,1 gives

```
[
{
"Name":"John",
"Surname":"Doe"
}
]
```

And pair 3, 5 gives

```
[
{
"Name":"Jane",
"Surname":"Dean"
}
]
```

Result of this WebClient call should be

```
[
{
"Name": "John",
"Surname: "Doe"
},
....
{
"Name": "Jane",
"Surname": "Dean"
}
]
```

I know about retry and repeat mechanics of Mono, I just can't figure how to do "multiple calls with different request parameters" part.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Flux.range` in combination with `flatMap`:

```java
Flux.range(1, 5)
    .flatMap(i -> Flux.range(1, 5).map(j -> Tuples.of(i, j)))
    .flatMap(t ->
        WebClient.create().get()
            .uri(uri -> uri.scheme("http")
                .host(myHost)
                .path(myPath)
                .queryParam("System", t.getT1())
                .queryParam("Form", t.getT2())
                .build())
            .exchange()
    )
    .flatMap(response -> /* Handle the response... */)
```

If the tuples that I have calculated in the example above are instead stored in a `Map<Integer, Integer>`, you have to change the code slightly:

```java
Flux.fromIterable(intIntMap.entrySet())
    .flatMap(entry ->
        WebClient.create().get()
            .uri(uri -> uri.scheme("http")
                .host(myHost)
                .path(myPath)
                .queryParam("System", entry.getKey())
                .queryParam("Form", entry.getValue())
                .build())
            .exchange()
    )
    .flatMap(response -> /* Handle the response... */)
```

With these approaches, you will never leave the functional world, resulting in a cleaner and more concise piece of code.

Comment: Wow! Nice answer. Very understandable!

Comment: Whoops. Yes, `Flux.range` is much better. Pretend my answer never existed :-)

Comment: Is there any way to process only this set:
 private static Map<Integer, Integer> allCombos = Stream.of(new Integer[][] {
   { 1, 1 },
   { 1, 2 },
   { 1, 3 },
   { 1, 4 },
   { 1, 5 },
   { 2, 1 },
   { 2, 3 },
   { 2, 4 },
   { 3, 1 },
   { 3, 3 },
   { 3, 4 },
 }).collect(Collectors.toMap(data -> data[0], data -> data[1]));

Comment: @SheykoDmitriy Is this a fixed sequence or can it somehow be calculated?

Comment: It's fixed sequence. Actually, you can pass any numbers from set {1-3, 1-5} (so first Flux.range would be (1,3)) but pairs (2,2), (2,5), (3,2) and (3,5) always produce error output (per endpoint specification these are not viable pairs)

Comment: @SheykoDmitriy I have added an alternative to my answer. See if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: @SheykoDmitriy One word of warning. The sequence you described above seems to have a pattern. It is always wise to let the computer calculate such patterns based on parameters instead of hardcoding it. If there is any chance of creating a function that returns this pattern for a set of paramters, do it. Future you will be thankful.